# Самый древний язык

Tags: недопустимая-метка, история

Правда ли, что русский язык самый древний на Земле?

Answer (score 3):

Чудинова со товарищи - ффтопку.
Я вот не побоюсь сказать, что он и иже с ним - фальсификаторы. Для этого не надо лично опровергать всю ту чушь, что они наговорили, достаточно посмотреть методы, коими они оперируют. Я даже не говорю об откровенной сенсационности всякого тезиса. Но незнание и предмета, и истории, огульное отрицание всего того, что было наработано предшественниками (вместе с самими предшественниками), отсутствие какой-либо доказательной базы, нетерпимость даже к малейшей критике - ну что ещё надо чтобы навсегда исключить всю это шайку из числа уважаеющих себя и науку ученых?

Вопрос о "первом" языке несостоятелен в принципе. Первым языком был язык первобытных людей, если не приматов. Индовевропейский язык - парродитель очень многих современных языков, но он не был первым, ибо люди разговаривали всегда. 
Кстати, вопрос о "первом" языке упирается ещё и в неразрешимость определения того, имеем ли мы в истороическом аспекте дело с одним языком или двумя разными. Скажем, русский и древнерусский - это один язык или разные? А русский язык XIX века и современный? Где критерии? 
Кстати, полное отсутствие в "трудах" чудиновцев и прочих фоменок от языка даже отдалённых указаний на то, что они считаю одним языком, а что разными, и приводит к тому, что они объявляют некий какой-то древний язык (реально существовавший или ими же выдуманный) то ли славянским, то ли вообще русским. А почему не китайским? Кстати, общепризнано (если не считать упомянутых чудинок), что из ныне сохранившихся языков наиболее близким к индоевропейскому праязыку стоит литовский, совсем не русский.

А всем, кто до сих пор верит в какой-то единый "первоязык" рекомендую перечитать соответвующую главу в книге Льва Васильевича Успенкого ["Слово о Словах"](http://lib.ru/PROZA/USPENSKIJ_L/slovo.txt).

Answer (score 1):

Есть версия (ее придерживается, например, ученый Валерий Чудинов), что русский язык действительно является одним из самых древних на земле. И, более того, славяне имели собственную, докириллическую письменность.
Однако официальная наука считает, что первым был индоевропейский праязык, легший в основу всех европейских и азиатских языков.

Comment: Да, да! Чудинов, Фоменко, Петрик... Гордость российской лженауки. И 2 из них - члены РАЕН, к тому же. Ба-а-альшие ученые.

Comment: Это не санскрит случайно?

Comment: Версия Чудинова мне тоже кажется сомнительной, но я не имею обыкновения поднимать на смех и отрицать то, что лично не могу точно и бесспорно опровергнуть. Чего и всем вам желаю.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, целиком и полностью согласен с Вами, хотя фамилию "Чудинов" впервые прочитал здесь, на форуме. Прежде всего, Чудинов - человек, а "Человек - это звучит гордо!". Ну а его теории - это уже производная, которая с самой функцией совпадает в единственном случае.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что русский народ, являющийся носителем русского языка, - молодой народ. Поэтому языки, носителями которых являются более древние народы, или народы, история которых насчитывает разные эпохи, например, китайцы, - более и значительно более древние языки.

Answer (score -1):

Об этом говорить весьма глупо, так как сейчас уже никто не знает, кто жил до нас. Я могу предположить, что нам просто обо всем врут, ведь никто не знает о тех событиях, которые происходили давным-давно. Я могу с уверенностью сказать, что не стоит верить, что существовали всякие короли, например. Это невозможно доказать, следовательно, нельзя говорить об этом.

Comment: > Если верить Вачовски мы загружены в матрицу.

Если вслед за солипсистами считать, что весь мир ложен, то далее следует, что всё равно требуется изучать законы этого "ложного" мира, так как о мире "настоящем" нам всё равно ничего не известно.

Историк действительно не знает, что было со всякими королями, также как криминалист не знает как произошло преступление. Но благодаря уликам и показаниям свидетелей зачастую картину можно восстановить достаточно точно. То что в силу недостатка этих улик истина находиться не всегда, не означает, что её не нужно искать.